# How to override generation of Lot/Serial in PO Receipts?

Tags: acumatica

I want to manipulate the generation of the lot and serial when the user press **Generate** in the Bin/lot/Serial sub-screen of the PO Receipt Screen.

I want to insert the rows of the lots with my own code but I can't find where the generation code is written in the BLC or so.

What I understand is that the class LSPOReceiptLine is the one responsible to generate the lots but I can't find it in the source code to override its function or to create a child class as I can't see LSPOReceiptLine's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```
public class POReceiptExt: PXGraphExtension<POReceiptEntry>
{
    public LSPOReceiptLineExt lsselect;
}

public class LSPOReceiptLineExt : LSPOReceiptLine
{
    public LSPOReceiptLineExt(PXGraph graph):
        base(graph)
    { 
    }

    public override IEnumerable GenerateLotSerial(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        //Doing magic here
        return base.GenerateLotSerial(adapter);//Remove this line if you don't want to call base method.
    }
}
```

Then using UI customization method, you replace all LSPOReceiptLine text with LSPOReceiptLineExt.
Hope it can help

Comment: I had started working on a similar solution, however it seems like the original LSPOReceiptLine doesn't get completely replaced by the new one, and the original code still gets called. I also tried overriding CreateNumbers without luck. You can see the same behaviour yourself by removing call to base class, you'll see you still have lot/serial numbers generated...

Comment: I was able to confirm through debugger than substituting LSPOReceiptLine with LSPOReceiptLineExt causes both instances to be created, rather than having LSPOReceiptLineExt really replace LSPOReceiptLine.

Comment: Let me check, in fact there's no implementation of GenerateLotSerial in LSPOReceiptLine, it's in the LSSelect class. I think the key is to override this method.

Comment: I got a solution from the dev team, but it's ugly and involves manually detaching all the handlers from LSPOReceiptLine and reattaching your own custom handlers.